# React Native + WebView + android emulator, WebGL support

Tags: android, react-native, webview, webgl

I'm trying to make React Native app with using WebGL (actually, Cesium lib if it matters) in WebView component. I've written a little app to test WebGL support: simple WebView (react-native-webview) loading http://get.webgl.org and run it on android emulator. As site says, if WebGL support is enabled, I should see a spinnig cube, but all I can see is *"Hmmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card"*.

And some interesting facts:
1) App based on AngularJs + Cordova + Ionic (which uses the same WebView-technology internally and the same Cesium lib) works perfectly on that emulator
2) I checked WebGL support (http://get.webgl.org, http://webglreport.com) in Chrome browser on emulator, and it's all good, no problems

So, the question is "what should I do with this?". Should I write native Java-based component for React? Or there are some settings in React Native WebView, in android app bundle files or somewhere else. Should I use another component provided WebView with WebGL support? Is that a problem with android emulator or with its settings? Well, I'm opened for any solutions and suggestions. There is a tiny chance that app will work fine on real device but it's critical for me to run and debug it on emulator.

Some technical information:
1) packages versions: react - 16.6.3, react-native - 0.57.8, react-native-webview - 2.14.3
2) OS: Windows 10, x64
3) emulator: official emulator from Google, API 25, tried with software and hardware graphics rendering settings

Comment: Same issue here, trying to use a WebView for Three.js

Comment: @russell Did manage to solve the problem, a half year later?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like emulator WebGL support on Webviews as been enabled on Android Q: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37129533